# changing datas inside switch(), accumulation

Tags: c++, accumulator

Im doing a project that stimulate the ATM in C++ and having some troubles with the accumulators, my question is: I am use switch (here is case 1) to change the values of 2 variables which are declared inside the function that contains the switch(), however the values only change inside case 1 and they reset themselves to the original value (like const declaration), so when I try to print the checking and saving (in case 3 and 4) it prints out the original amount (1000). So I dont know what I did wrong here. Problem is not with the amount, I have tried replacing amount with a numeric value but still doesnt work.
Please help

```
int transactions()
{   
    double checking = 1000.00, saving = 1000.00;
    double amount;
    switch (inputRange(menu()))
    {
    case 1: system("cls");
            amount = getAmount("Enter an amount to transfer from checking to saving: ");
            checking -= amount; 
            saving += amount;
            cout << checking << " " << saving; // they only change inside case 1
            cout << "\nTransaction completed! \n\nPress ENTER to return to main menu...";
            cin.ignore(99,'\n');
            break;
```

updates*** I already got it guys, thanks, just forgot about the &, this works

```
   int transactions(double &checkBal, double &saveBal)
{       
    double amount;

    //set precision
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    switch (inputRange(menu()))
    {
    case 1: system("cls");
            checkingToSaving (getAmount("Enter an amount to transfer from checking to saving: "), checkBal, saveBal);
            cout << "\nTransaction completed! \n\nPress ENTER to return to main menu...";
            cin.ignore(99,'\n');
            break;
```

Comment: Look at lifetime of 'checking, 'saving' etc, (storage class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `checking` and `saving` only exist for the duration of a single call to `transactions()`.

They spring into existence when `transactions()` is called, get initialized, your code changes them, and they disappear the moment `transactions()` returns. When the function is called again, the whole cycle repeats.

The two variables need to exist outside the function (probably as data members of some class).

Comment: I declared those variables in main() and pass those values to transactions(), the values still wouldnt change, what do you suggest? thanks

Comment: @user1986597: You need to pass them by reference and not by value. A better approach is to do what I suggested, and make them data members of some class.

Comment: sorry but I'm still confused, I pass the values like this `int transactions(double checkBal, double saveBal)` but still no working

Comment: Like @NPE says, passing in by value will just not work - the parameters get copied and only the copy changes.  Use a class instance for your customer and pass it in by pointer or reference.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a 'customer' class, (with name, address, savings, checking etc. members).  Create instances outside 'transactions' and pass in an instance as a parameter.

That, or DB.

Comment: yea as I replied above I initialized those variables in main() which is outside transactions() and pass as parameters like this `int transactions(double checkBal, double saveBal)` but still doesnt work

Comment: 'int transactions(Customer *thisCustomer);' or possibly 'int transactions(Customer& thisCustomer);'

Comment: A pointer doesn't make sense here, as you never want a null customer.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain well.. here in this example, OK, yes.  In a 'real' app, where varying numbers of dynamically-alocated customers, maybe of differing classes, are stored in containers, queued up in inter-thread comms etc, references have 'issues'.  Best not to go there to avoid jihad.. :)

Comment: @MartinJames Just No! Worst comes to worst you just overload the function definition, and take a pointer from the reference and pass it into the pointer version.

Comment: OK, then who owns the data, the reference or the pointer derived from it?

Answer (score -1):

A crude answer to your immediate problem is to use static variables:

```
int transactions()
{   
    static double checking = 1000.00;
    static double saving = 1000.00;
    .
    .
```

This type of approach only gives you one instance of checking and saving.  If you want to extend your program to have multiple accounts you should look at using class instances to hold the data:

```
class Account{
    double checking;
    double saving;
public:
    int transactions();
};
```

Comment: thanks, I got it now, but between static variables and pass by ref using &, which one is better? (this is just a simple program so I dont wanna get involved into class)

Comment: @user1986597 Don't use static variables. They are globals in disguise.

Comment: They just are, for multiple reasons. Carry on programming for any length of time and all will become clear, (unless you use a lot of globals, whereupon everything will become most unclear:).  Effective and efficient software is more about data than code - if you get the data right, writing the code becomes, (almost), straightforward.  If you are going to hand in this project for marking, try very hard to avoid globals/statics for classes like customer data.

Comment: @user1986597 Google it? Read around the subject a bit... http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad